# Why is Law unable to use Shambles against Doflamingo and simply drown him in the ocean?

Tags: one-piece

He could've simply replaced a fish in the ocean for Doflamingo. Unless I've missed something.

Comment: Being the DF's weakness, I wouldn't be surprised if Law has no control of anything underwater.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, Shambles is nothing but a technique which interchanges positions of two objects! DF can operate on almost anything in the world, but as we know its weakness is sea and sea related things like Sea Stone. Your power becomes null when you interact with the sea. Pushing Doflamingo into the sea will require pulling out some sea water and exchanging its position with Doffy, which clearly is not possible. Think about it: the guy Señor Pink has the ability to swim anywhere and the irony is he can't swim in the sea.

Comment: Then how did Aokiji froze the sea ? How could Luffy use "elephant gun" against kraken ?

Answer (score 0):

Doflamingo is well aware of how Law's powers work, and he made sure for most of their interactions that Law coulst set uo his Room by keeping him on the defensive. And along with that, he'd need to be near the water first for that to happen and Doflamingo probably wouldn't let that happen.

Also, DF powers don't instantly become inactive when they, or the user touch sea water. This was proven when Aokiji touched the ocean physically, then froze it for miles across when first meeting the Straw Hats.